# How to specify api docs url for swagger ui in spring boot (open api v3)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have a spring boot application with open-api 3 that is deployed in Kubernetes (spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.4.RELEASE). The rest endpoints are accessible through ingress, so URL is something like:

```
https://host/ingress-path
```

I have the problem that as soon as the application is deployed to ingress, api-docs are available too via:

```
https://host/ingress-path/v3/api-docs
```

When I open Swagger UI I have 404 because it seems like Swagger UI is looking into https://host/v3/api-docs... When I open

```
https://host/ingress-path/swagger-ui/index.html
```

and put `https://host/ingress-path/v3/api-docs` to 'Expore' and run it, I have all my API discovered.

Can anybody suggest how to set a server for UI using some spring property, etc?

Currently I have this (downloaded from https://host/ingress-path/v3/api-docs.yaml)

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: My API
  description: My API description
  version: v0.0.1
servers:
- url: https://host
  description: Generated server url
```

This API is autogenerated. I suppose that `server` has to have `url: https://host/ingress-path`

Seems like I need pathProvider with relative path, like described here:

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/170

But I cannot find such thing in open-api 3.

Can you please help me?

Thanks!

P.S. I suppose that I can fix it via config:

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
    path: '/v3/api-docs'
  swagger-ui:
    path: '/swagger-ui'
    config-url: '/ingress-path/v3/api-docs/swagger-config'
    url: '/ingress-path/v3/api-docs'
    doc-expansion: none
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: Hi @Varun. 
Actually I posted possible solution. I did not really tested it because we decided that we don't need it on our service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks Cunuu Kum

I tested your piece of code and confirm that it's working.

The key part is ***spring-ui.url***

Reposting here so that it helps others

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
    path: '/v3/api-docs'
  swagger-ui:
    path: '/swagger-ui'
    config-url: '/ingress-path/v3/api-docs/swagger-config'
    url: '/ingress-path/v3/api-docs'
    doc-expansion: none
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
```