# Can springdoc read and combine configs from autoscan and file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-ui

Can I somehow combine these config?
I can define json which /api-docs gives in /open-api.json but may be there is any other way to just specify these configs together.

```
springdoc:
  api-docs.path: /api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
    enabled: true
```

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
    url: /open-api.json
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify api docs url for swagger ui in spring boot (open api v3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968902/how-to-specify-api-docs-url-for-swagger-ui-in-spring-boot-open-api-v3)